# Determine inverse function

Tags: calculus

I have

$$f(x)=x^5-5x+3$$
and I should determine the largest interval around x=0 where f(x) is invertible. I understand that I should switch f(x) to y and then make some expression with x=??. But how do I do that? I can't imagine that I should get all the roots or something like that.

Comment: That would be very difficult, to actually solve for $f^{-1}(x)$.  Better is to use a bit of calculus to find whether $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing in a neighborhood of $x=0$ and work out the largest interval containing $x=0$ where the function remains so.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$$f'(x) = 5x^4 - 5$$

set that equal to $0$ and get the turning points